# Meteor user search log

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, logging, authentication, meteor

For a meteor app I want to log the searches of the users and let each user see their previous searches including the date and time.

Currently, I use this working search with bootstrap-3.

```
<template name="search">
  <div class="input-group" style="margin:1em 1em 0 1em;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="padding:1em; font-size: 120%; color:black; padding:0em 1em 0em 1em; height:2em; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 0;" placeholder="Start searching" id="search"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="cursor:pointer;"></span>
    </span> 
  </div>
</template>
```

Now I would like to store the users searches, in a collection I assume e.g.

```
Searches = new Meteor.Collection("Searches");
```

and only allow each user to see their previous searches. I added accounts-ui and accounts-password and {{>loginButtons}} to the html.

How to I save the searches (best with date and time) and show them to the users (on an extra page)? How do I restrict the view for the users in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a publication for search history.

**Server**

```
// will publish all searches for a user, could also sort by date and limit
Meteor.publish('searchHistory', function () {
  return Searches.find({userId: this.userId});
});
```

You should also set permissions on the Searches collection. http://docs.meteor.com/#allow

**Client**

```
// get my search history
Meteor.subscribe('searchHistory');

// insert a new search document when enter key is pressed
Template.search.events({
  'keydown #search': function (e, t) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      Searches.insert({
        userId: Meteor.userId(), 
        value: t.$('#search').val(),
        date: Date.now()
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit**: Here is a simple search history template.

```
// sort searches by date for display
Template.history.searches = function () {
  return Searches.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}});
};

<template name="history">
  {{#each searches}}<div>{{value}}</div>{{/each}}
</template>
```